# Adaptive brightness is not present in notification bar and altogether does not work

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, screen-brightness

My Nexus 7 2013 has updated with OTA update to Android 5.0.1.

The notification bar has changed. Now when I change brightness, there is no button for auto-adjustment. It currently looks like this:

[image]

In settings, I can find Adaptive brightness settings - optimize brightness level for available light. However this does not work as expected. It just seems I have two different brightness settings. If I turn it on and set manually via notification bar to maximum, it is maximum, although the settings is ON. Then I turn it off and set it to maximum and it lets me do it too. When it is turned on, the brightness is just slightly darker than the turned OFF mode. However, it is always exactly as I set it with this small offset. It does not correspond to the external light.

It seems like it is a bug, but I can't tell. Do you experience the same with your Nexus 7 2013? Is the "auto" button missing in all lollipops? Does it mean that when you want to go to auto-brightness mode you have to enter settings and brightness via more like 5 clicks? (two swipe downs, settings, brightness, turn on)

Comment: It's the same with my Nexus 7 2012 on 5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android has removed "Auto-brightness" in place of "Adaptive brightness" on Android 5.0 Lollipop.

From [Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/06/26/android-l-feature-spotlight-auto-brightness-is-gone-adaptive-brightness-takes-its-place/),

> If you're looking for the auto-brightness switch on the Android L preview build, you won't find it. That's because it's been replaced with the adaptive brightness toggle. [...]
>
> In short, adaptive brightness is like *quasi-autobrightness*. You're essentially setting a "range" of available brightness levels when this feature is turned on, so that if you have display brightness set to 50%, the phone may only actually adjust itself between 40 and 70% brightness in a given situation. This is as opposed to completely automatic brightness, which typically gives you the full spectrum of brightness adjustments depending on the ambient light. The problem with fully automatic brightness is that's it's often slow and a poor judge of what level of brightness your eyes really need. So, this adaptive mode allows you to set a baseline brightness that the phone will then adjust from based on your surroundings.

If adaptive brightness is active, it will be always active even if the brightness is changed from the quick setting panel, because it will only change the baseline brightness.

On the other hand, it's correct that there is no quick setting to toggle "Adaptive brightness" on stock ROM. It seems the only way to do that is with 3rd-party apps, but I didn't found any as of current writing.

Answer (score 0):

It is adaptive brightness. Slider determines the sensitivity of the brightness in case adaptive brightness is turned on. If you keep the slider on 50%, it will work the same as auto brightness. If it is 30%, then the brightness will be equal to the brightness of the external illumination which is 20% less than current illumination. So, essentially it helps people save power or improve readability by adjusting the sensitivity of brightness according to individual preference